# How to run a websocket client in my Java Web App

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web-applications, websocket

I need to run a Java websocket client that listens to some updates from another 3rd part websocket server.

The client needs to be deployed as part of a Java webapp.

The requirement is that the client must be listening to the updates continuously.

What is the right way to do this?

I was thinking of invoking the said java code from a servlet. Is that recommended?

Edit: I have the code for the websocket (I am using Tyrus) but I am confused about the correct way to link it to my webapp. i.e., how to ensure that the websocket is running continuously.

Answer (score 1):

I would make it a separate class. If you want to connect and continuously listen while the application is running, you'll probably need to run it in a separate thread that kicks off when the application starts.

Threading and concurrency is a the start of a pretty deep rabbit hole, but something like a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) with a single thread would probably work.

From there, if you're running Jetty embedded stick the Executor logic in your main method; if you're running it as a .war, you'll have to configure it to run when the web application starts.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-client`

```
WebSocketClient client = new WebSocketClient();
SimpleEchoSocket socket = new SimpleEchoSocket();
try {
     client.start();
     URI echoUri = new URI(destUri);
     ClientUpgradeRequest request = new ClientUpgradeRequest();
     client.connect(socket, echoUri, request);
     System.out.printf("Connecting to : %s%n", echoUri);
     socket.awaitClose(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 } catch (Throwable t) {
      t.printStackTrace();
 } finally {
    try {
         client.stop();
     } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
```

---

- [read more](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-websocket-client-api.html)

Comment: What would be the right way to invoke this code in a Webapp? I actually have the code of websocket client (Tyrus) so not looking for code to write websocket but rather how to run it on a servlet container.

Comment: _I need to run a Java websocket client that listens to some updates from another 3rd part websocket server._

Comment: if you mean you want to serve a websocket connection from your server you need a supported container

Comment: No I just need to run a websocket client (lets say the one in your code). How do I invoke this in my web app (which is a bunch of JSP pages and servlets)?

Comment: it is confusing, you want to consume websocket server side and process those data ? if yes you can write a scheduler or something that keeps listening to thirdparty websocket and processes data